# Add small scroll animation, when scrolled down then only need to show another row

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have some images as shown in the layout here.

[image]

Currently all images are showing at once. What I want instead is to show only single row of images at a time, I would like to have an animation, when user scolls, then show another row and hide previous one, similariy next scrolling show next row. In case if user scroll upwards, we need to show images from previous row. Like that.
Can't get a clue on how to achieve it. Here, is my current code.

```css
.parallax-window {
    min-height: 400px;
    background: transparent;
}

.service-box-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 2fr);
    gap: 15px;
}

.service-box-container .service-box{
      grid-column: span 2;
}
.service-box-container .service-box:nth-child(5n+4), .service-box-container .service-box:nth-child(5n+5) {
    grid-column: span 3;
}

.service-box-container img{
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  height: 460px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/parallax.js/1.4.2/parallax.min.js"></script>
<div class="service-box-container parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360">

  <div class="service-box">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" class="" alt="">
      </figure>
  </div>
  
  <div class="service-box">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" class="" alt="">
      </figure>
  </div>
  
  <div class="service-box">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" class="" alt="">
      </figure>
  </div>
  
  <div class="service-box">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" class="" alt="">
      </figure>
  </div>
  
  <div class="service-box">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" class="" alt="">
      </figure>
  </div>
  
  <div class="service-box">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" class="" alt="">
      </figure>
  </div>
  
  <div class="service-box">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" class="" alt="">
      </figure>
  </div>
  
  <div class="service-box">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" class="" alt="">
      </figure>
  </div>
  
  <div class="service-box">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" class="" alt="">
      </figure>
  </div>
  
  <div class="service-box">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" class="" alt="">
      </figure>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.parallax-window').parallax({});
    });
</script>
```

#PS: I have used parallax js as well, so I would love to keep those parallax effect as well.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sj7q50ap/).

Comment: you probably want to look for *lazy loading images* - you'll find a lot code that way

Comment: @Bravo could you please share a js fiddle? I don't know if if lazy loading alone would hide the first row, when second row is loaded.

Comment: no, because I haven't written the code for you - you're right, lazy loading probably not required ... so, I'm of no use

Comment: okay, no problem

Comment: When exactly do you want one row to disappear and the other to appear: when the row *begins* to scroll out of view? When it has *completely* scrolled out of view? Somewhere in between? What is the expected behavior if the viewport isn't tall enough to show one row of images?

Comment: @kmoser Somewhere in between. could you show me with certain height? This height should be little longer than that of image.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following *might* be what you are looking for.

**Note:** You should run the following snippet in "Full-page" mode.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
#scrollbox {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: auto;
    background-color: #eee;
    float: left;
}
.service-box {
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.service-box img {
    margin: 0px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="scrollbox">

  <div class="service-box">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" class="" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="service-box">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" class="" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="service-box">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" class="" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="service-box">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" class="" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="service-box">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" class="" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="service-box">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" class="" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="service-box">
    <img alt="Fourth of July 2022" height="200" src="https://google.com/logos/doodles/2022/fourth-of-july-2022-6753651837109457-law.gif" title="Fourth of July 2022" width="500">
  </div>

  <div class="service-box">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" class="" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="service-box">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" class="" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="service-box">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" class="" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="service-box">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" class="" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
<script>
// When we get to within 30 pixels of the bottom of a row,
// we show the next row:
const THRESHOLD = 30;
window.onload = function() {
    let s = document.getElementById('scrollbox');
    let children = s.children;
    let scrollHeight;
    let maxHeight = 0;
    let maxWidth = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < children.length; ++i) {
        let child = children[i];
        let style = child.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(child);
        if (i === 0) {
            scrollHeight = child.offsetTop - parseInt(style.marginTop);
        }
        let heightWithoutMargins = parseInt(style.height) +
                                   parseInt(style.paddingTop) +
                                   parseInt(style.paddingBottom) +
                                   parseInt(style.borderTop) +
                                   parseInt(style.borderBottom);
        let totalHeight = heightWithoutMargins + parseInt(style.marginTop) + parseInt(style.marginBottom);
        if (totalHeight > maxHeight) {
            maxHeight = totalHeight;
        }
        let widthWithoutMargins = parseInt(style.width) +
                                  parseInt(style.paddingLeft) +
                                  parseInt(style.paddingRight) +
                                  parseInt(style.borderLeft) +
                                  parseInt(style.borderRight);
        let totalWidth = widthWithoutMargins + parseInt(style.marginLeft) + parseInt(style.marginRight);
        if (totalWidth > maxWidth) {
            maxWidth = totalWidth;
        }
        child.top = child.offsetTop - scrollHeight;
        child.bottom = child.top + heightWithoutMargins - THRESHOLD;
        child.marginTop = parseInt(style.marginTop);
        child.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    s.style.height = maxHeight + 'px';
    // Allow for the scrollbar:
    s.style.width = (maxWidth + 18) + 'px';
    let currentVisible = null;
    let currentY = 0;
    s.onscroll = function() {
        let yTop = s.scrollTop;
        let yBottom = yTop + maxHeight;
        // Find all visible:
        let visible = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < children.length; ++i) {
            let child = children[i];
            let top = child.top;
            let bottom = child.bottom;
            if ((top >= yTop && bottom < yBottom) || (top< yTop && bottom > yTop)) {
                visible.push(children[i]);
            }
        }
        if (currentVisible) {
            currentVisible.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
        if (visible.length) {
            currentVisible = yTop >= currentY ? visible.pop() : visible[0];
            currentVisible.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
        else {
            currentVisible = null;
        }
        currentY = yTop;
    };
    s.onscroll(); // kick things off
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried it to implement with the image but it is not working, could you please check this jsfiddle and let me know what I did wrong here. https://jsfiddle.net/91Lb6gaq/13/

Comment: Frankly, I don't know anything about the parallax.js you are running and how it interacts with what I have done. It's very possible that my code is incompatible with that code. I have updated my code to support variable width and height images and am using your image repeatedly with one from goggle.com to demonstrate the variable height and width support. I am sorry I could not be more helpful. I definitly needed to modify the code to run on a `window.onload` event or a JQuery `$(document).ready()` call.

Answer (score -3):

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    console.log(scrollY); //You will see numbers increasing and decreasing in console
    if(scrollY === yournecessarynumber) {
      // For appearing the necessary height in the window.innerHeight
      // If you replace with yournecessarynumber with number the function below will start working after reacing that number and animate your element with appearing from bottom and opacity
      element.style.transform: 'scale(1), translateY(0)',
      element.style.display: 'block'
    }
})

      // You should use it for recognizing the style and giving alter in animation
      element.style.transform: 'scale(0), translateY(1000%)',
      element.style.display: 'none'
```

Comment: showing syntax error

Comment: There's a syntax error, and also you should try and add text explaining what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.